# Repository or Gateway pattern in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, design-patterns, architecture

How can I implement the Repository or Gateway pattern in Ruby?

I come from a C# world and I usually abstract away my data access but with ActiveRecord as the default data access mechanism in Ruby, it's not obvious how to accomplish that.

What I usually would do in C# is work with abstract interfaces and then have a concrete implementation for `EFCustomerRepository`, `NHibernateCustomerRepository` and `InMemoryCustomerRepository` and depending on the situation I inject the matching concrete implementation.

So now, what’s the Ruby way?!

As far as I understand it, in dynamic languages you would not need something like DI (dependency injection).
And Ruby has powerful language features to allow things like mixins.

But you would define the mixin to use statically on class or module-level?

How do I write my business logic if I want to develop against an in-memory repository and in production I would switch to my ActiveRecord-Repository?

If might be on the wrong path here since I'm used to thinking in a statically typed language. How would someone tackle this task the Ruby way? Basically I want to make my persistence layer abstract and it's implementations interchangeable.

**EDIT:** I am referring to [robert c. martins (unclebob) keynote about architecture](http://confreaks.com/videos/759-rubymidwest2011-keynote-architecture-the-lost-years)

Thanks for any help...

Comment: http://lancecarlson.github.com/2012/05/15/dci-and-decoupling-business-logic-from-ruby-on-rails.html this is something someone did as a response to the Uncle Bob article. More to come.

Comment: I'm also looking for a gem which implements the repository pattern.

Answer (score 3):

I get what you are saying. I come from a .NET background as well. Abstracting away your business logic & persistance logic is imo a good idea. I haven't found a gem that does it for you yet. But you can easily roll something simple yourself. In the end a repository pattern is basically a class that delegates to your persistance layer.

Here is what I do:

```
require 'active_support/core_ext/module/attribute_accessors'

class GenericRepository

  def initialize(options = {})
    @scope = options[:scope]
    @association_name = options[:association_name]
  end

  def self.set_model(model, options = {})
    cattr_accessor :model
    self.model = model
  end

  def update(record, attributes)
    check_record_matches(record)
    record.update_attributes!(attributes)
  end

  def save(record)
    check_record_matches(record)
    record.save
  end

  def destroy(record)
    check_record_matches(record)
    record.destroy
  end

  def find_by_id(id)
    scoped_model.find(id)
  end

  def all
    scoped_model.all
  end

  def create(attributes)
    scoped_model.create!(attributes)
  end

private

  def check_record_matches(record)
    raise(ArgumentError, "record model doesn't match the model of the repository") if not record.class == self.model
  end

  def scoped_model
    if @scope
      @scope.send(@association_name)
    else
      self.model
    end
  end

end
```

And then you could for example have a Post repository.

```
class PostRepository < GenericRepository

  set_model Post

  # override all because we also want to fetch the comments in 1 go.
  def all
    scoped_model.all(:include => :comments)
  end

  def count()
    scoped_model.count
  end

end
```

Just instantiate it in your controller in a before_filter or initialize or wherever. In this case I'm scoping it to the current_user so that it only fetches those records and automatically create posts only for the current user.

```
def initialize
  @post_repository = PostRepository.new(:scope => @current_user, :association_name => 'posts')
end

def index
  @posts = @post_repository.all
  respond_with @posts, :status => :ok
end
```

I came across https://github.com/bkeepers/morphine which is a tiny DI framework. It could work for you :) But DI isn't a heavily used pattern in ruby. Also, I instantiate my repos in order to scope them to a current user or something else.

I'm on a quest to find the right way to do just what you ask and do a little write-up about it if I ever do find it. But for now it's already sufficient to make the clean cut between persistance & my controllers. If this is done properly it won't be a big hassle to switch to a different system later on. Or add caching etc.

Comment: I liked the way you described above and tried to implement this in one of my app. But I got stuck on where to put/add the Database connections and ActiveRecord stuffs? Can you enhance the above with a simple ActiveRecord/sqlite3 db connection and methods?

Answer (score 2):

Well, ActiveRecord already provides abstract persistence layer - it has [several different adapters](http://rubydoc.info/gems/activerecord/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters) allowing it to use different database backends. Also, it's open-source so you are free to take a look at how it has been achieved.

Upon the first glance you can see that it also has an [AbstractAdapter](http://rubydoc.info/gems/activerecord/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/AbstractAdapter) that all other adapters inherit, however, as Ruby is dynamic, duck-typing language, `AbstractAdapter` doesn't have to contain abstract methods which will be overridden in children classes, neither defines a "contract" that they should honour.

Edit:

Here's a simple sketch on how you could abstract away your storage in Ruby, not sure which pattern exactly it is:

```
# say you have an AR model of a person
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
end

# and in-memory store of persons (simply, a hash)
IN_MEMORY_STORE = {
  :Person => ['Tim', 'Tom', 'Tumb']
}

# this will abstract access
class MyAbstractModel
  def initialize item, adapter
    @item = item
    @adapter = adapter
  end

  # get all elements from the store
  def all
    case @adapter
    when :active_record
      # pull from database:
      Object.const_get(@item).all
    when :in_memory_store
      # get from in-memory store
      IN_MEMORY_STORE[@item]
    else
      raise "Unknown adapter"
    end
  end
end

# get all Persons from in-memory storage...
p MyAbstractModel.new(:Person, :in_memory_store).all
# ...and from a database
p MyAbstractModel.new(:Person, :active_record).all
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply... I was wondering how the duck-typing language handels things like this... And how I would stay independent from frameworks, so if one day ActiveRecord is not hype anymore and there is a new kid on the block I'll be able to switch easily...

Comment: It not because it is the `new kid on the block` that you absolutely have to use it... You can keep using technologies that are `not the hype anymore` and still make "good" software.

Answer (score 1):

@serverinfo, I don't know much about C#. But when I came to Ruby from a Java/C background, I was blown away when I realized how flexible this language really is. You say that your real problem here is to "abstract away your persistence layer and make it exchangeable". You also asked "how will I write the business logic".

I suggest that you throw away your preconceptions and ask yourself: "how would I *like* to express data access/storage within my business logic layer"? Don't worry about what you think can or can't be done; if you can figure out how you would *like* the interface to work, there is probably a way it can be done in Ruby.

You will also have to decide how you want to specify the concrete implementation to be used. Is it possible you will want to use a different data store for different model objects? Might you want to switch at run-time? Would you like to specify the backend to be used in a configuration file, or in code? If you can decide what you *want* to do, there are lots of people on Stack Overflow who can help you figure out *how* to do it.

Comment: Yes thanks for the reply... I was trying to understand this: http://confreaks.com/videos/759-rubymidwest2011-keynote-architecture-the-lost-years ... and you right totaly mindshift - but good =)